# NSFetchedResultController sort table view sections by multiple keys

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

**Problem**:

in my CoreData model, i have two entities called List and Item, they have one-to-many relationship. There are 2 types of List in my current design, system list and user list. System list is created by system during the very first launch and user list will be created by users anytime.

### In my TVC, i would like to present all the items grouped by their associated lists(use list name as section title), in addition, i want all the system lists always placed on top of the user lists.

For instance, consider i have all the instances of list in DB as below:

System list: *Inbox*

User list: *FruitList*, *ShoppingList*

The expected result will be:

- *Inbox*

  - *InboxItem1*
  - *InboxItem2*
- *FruitList*

  - *FruitListItem1*
- *ShoppingList*

  - *Apple*
  - *Orange*

**The Approach:**

With FRC, i can a achieve the first goal by setting sectionNameKeyPath as "list_name" to the FRC. But i have problem with fixing position the system list (*Inbox* in this case, it should always at index 0). However, the problem comes as user input their list with name start with "A" - "J" and all those lists will be placed on top of *inbox*, and i did try to fix it by adding "list_type" as secondary sort key, but it doesn't work.

```
NSFetchRequest *requst = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:ENTITY_ITEM];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"belongsToList.list_name" ascending:YES],
                                [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"belongsToList.list_type" ascending:NO]];

requst.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
requst.predicate = [self predicateForListType:type selectedList:list];
requst.fetchBatchSize = 20;

_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:requst managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"belongsToList.list_name" cacheName:nil];
```

**Temporary solution:**

The temp solution i can think of to solve this problem is to add prefix string to the list name and store them as another attribute from DB and use it as sectionNameKeyPath.

e.g.
"0-" - for system lists ("Inbox" -> "0-Inbox")

"1-" - for user list ("ShoppingList" -> "1-ShoppingList")

and remove the prefix in `-tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` . But this solution creates overhead and i think there should be much better solution out there since it is a common problem that all developers will face while they are dealing with FRC and TBV.

Any input??!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a transient attribute like `sectionIdentifier` to the `List` entity and sort like this: use

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"list.sectionIdentifier" ascending:YES]
```

as the *first* sort descriptor.

The sectionIdentifier could be anything which sorts the way you intend ("System" first) and from which you can reconstruct the proper section name to return in `titleForHeaderInSection`.

Comment: "isSystemList" attribute is similar as what i did for my model (adding "belongsToList.list_type"). the really issue is that the sectionNameKeyPath need to be same as the first sort description key according to apple's doc, as result the section will always sort by the section name then list type.

Comment: You just need to sort items such that they're ordered by section. So sort by `list.isSystemList` then by `list.name`.

Comment: First of all, i have to set sectionNameKeyPath to "list_name" cause it is used to group items by their associated lists. secondly, according to apple's doc "If the controller generates sections, the first sort descriptor in the array is used to group the objects into sections; its key must either be the same as sectionNameKeyPath or the relative ordering using its key must match that using sectionNameKeyPath." so the first sort descriptor key must be "list_name" as well, so to my knowledge, their is no way to sort by "isSystemList" then by "list_name"

Comment: Make a new transient attribute `sectionName` that makes sure that the system section is first. Then just sort by section name and use it as the section name key path. In `titleForHeaderInSection:` you can return the final string based on this information.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Mundi, can you elaborate more ? and i think the attribute that can be the key of the sort descriptor must be persisted attribute, correct me if i am wrong about this. :)

Comment: No, actually, you can sort by transient attribute as well. But even persisting it will not be a big hit on resources I think. Updated my answer.